# After an oil change, my car, 2004 Hyundai Elantra has an oil leak in the front of my car, and it smell like gas

Tags: oil, hyundai, stall

After an oil change, my car has a oil leak and it randomly dies whenever I drive very slow, my foot on the brake all the time, for example while I am driving and looking for an address. What should I do?  I took my car to an auto shop, they said the oil change did not tighten the cap, so they tighten the cap for me. They said my idle control valve is getting bad, so they change that and the idle control valve for the random dying . I took my car home and found the oil still leaking, not sure about the random dying because from the shop to my house is 1 mile.
What I should do? Is this related to the oil changed?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible the original shop dripped oil on the engine while refilling it and that oil continues to drip onto the ground.  It *might* stop after a while.

It's also possible they did not tighten the oil filter correctly (over or under tightened it).

Can the second shop take a look for those conditions?

I don't think the stalling has anything to do with the oil.  You might be OK in that regard after the idle control repair you had.